# Submitting dates via 3 drop downs getting submit as an array entry

Tags: php, forms, post

This is just a form for my own use, however if I ever put it out there, I want make it a little secure and idiot proof.
Rather than getting way in over my head with javascript I thought lets keep it simple with 3 drop down list for the date. Unfortunately,I think I am still unable to tread water. When I try to extract to variables i.e `$date = $_POST('day')` it does does not work.
My `print_r($_POST)` displays:`Array ( [year] => 2014 [month] => 11 [day] => 18 [submit] => submit )`  why am I getting `submit` in the array?
trying to `echo $day;` gives a E_ERROR : type 1 -- Function name must be a string -- at line 20

My thought was to run a checkdate($month,$day,$year) then combine them as a `'YYYY-MM-DD'` to submit to the Database.

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
print_r($_POST);
$day = $_POST('day');
echo $day;


}


$m = date('m');
$y = date('Y');
$d = date('d');

$days= range(1,31);
$months = range(1,12);
$years = range( $y-1, $y+1) ;
?>
<form  method="post">
<?php
echo '<select name="year">';
    foreach ($years as $year ){
        echo '<option value=' . $year ;
            if( $year == $y ) echo ' selected' ;
        echo '>' .  $year . '</option>';
    }
echo '</select> '; 

echo '<select name="month">';
    foreach ($months as $month ){
        echo '<option value=' . $month ;
            if( $month == $m ) echo ' selected' ;
        echo '>' .  $month . '</option>';
    }
echo '</select> '; 

echo '<select name="day">';
    foreach ($days as $day ){
        echo '<option value=' . $day ;
            if( $day == $d ) echo ' selected' ;
        echo '>' .  $day . '</option>';
    }
echo '</select> '; 
 echo '<input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit"><br />';
 echo '</form>';

 ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$_POST` is an array. Change it to:

```
$day = $_POST[ 'day' ];
```

Comment: WOW you are fast, I posted the question even after finding the answer thinking it may help someone else. (or I can refer back to it if I screw up again).I then posted the answer but you still beat me. However, I am still curious why `[submit] => submit` is showing up in the `print_r`. is this normal ?

Comment: because submit is an input in the form so it is also submitted. if you don't want it submitted, you can use JavaScript to make an onsubmit function and remove it from the form prior to submitting

Comment: I don't care if `submit` is submitted, but I am trying to make sure I am doing things as correctly as possible in a way my mind will understand. So it is OK that it shows up and I can rest easy?

Answer (score 0):

Further examination revealed I missed using `$day = $_POST['day'];`. I was using `$day = $_POST('day');`